# How to Vectorize Dependent For-Loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I'm working on a function that takes a 1xn vector `x` as input and returns a nxn matrix `L`.
I'd like to speed things up by vectorizing the loops, but there's a catch that puzzles me: loop index `b` depends on loop index `a`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
x = x(:); 
n = length(x);
L = zeros(n, n);
for a = 1 : n,
    for b = 1 : a-1,
        c = b+1 : a-1;
        if all(x(c)' < x(b) + (x(a) - x(b)) * ((b - c)/(b-a))),
            L(a,b) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: A side note for variables in Matlab: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've renamed ``i``,``j``,``k`` to ``a``,``b``,``c``.

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize this, but all([]) evaluates to true. So, for example, when a == 2, b will be 1, and c will be []. This will end up making L(a,b) 1. You may need to think through your b and c ranges (I may be wrong; maybe this is how you intended it to work).

Comment: @ioums That's how the code is intended to work.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the application?

Comment: @BasSwinckels Imagine ``x`` as a bar graph. If the top of bar ``a`` can be connected with the top of bar ``b`` using a straight line (without intersecting any of the bars in between them), the code puts a '1' in ``L(a,b)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick test, it looks like you are doing something with the lower triangle only. You might be able to vectorize using ugly tricks like `ind2sub` and `arrayfun` similar to this

```
tril_lin_idx = find(tril(ones(n), -1));
[A, B] = ind2sub([n,n], tril_lin_idx);
C = arrayfun(@(a,b) b+1 : a-1, A, B, 'uniformoutput', false); %cell array
f = @(a,b,c) all(x(c{:})' < x(b) + (x(a) - x(b)) * ((b - c{:})/(b-a)));
L = zeros(n, n);
L(tril_lin_idx) = arrayfun(f, A, B, C);
```

I cannot test it, since I do not have `x` and I don't know the expected result. I normally like vectorized solutions, but this is maybe pushing it a bit too much :). I would stick to your explicit for-loop, which might be much clearer and which Matlab's JIT should be able to speed up easily. You could replace the if with `L(a,b) = all(...)`.

**Edit1**

Updated version, to prevent wasting `~ n^3` space on `C`:

```
tril_lin_idx = find(tril(ones(n), -1));
[A, B] = ind2sub([n,n], tril_lin_idx);
c = @(a,b) b+1 : a-1;
f = @(a,b) all(x(c(a, b))' < x(b) + (x(a) - x(b)) * ((b - c(a, b))/(b-a)));
L = zeros(n, n);
L(tril_lin_idx) = arrayfun(f, A, B);
```

**Edit2**

Slight variant, which does not use ind2sub and which should be more easy to modify in case `b` would depend in a more complex way on `a`. I inlined `c` for speed, it seems that especially calling the function handles is expensive.

```
[A,B] = ndgrid(1:n);
v = B<A; % which elements to evaluate
f = @(a,b) all(x(b+1:a-1)' < x(b) + (x(a) - x(b)) * ((b - (b+1:a-1))/(b-a)));
L = false(n);
L(v) = arrayfun(f, A(v), B(v));
```

Comment: Thanks, your vectorized code returns the expected results - however, (to my surprise) it's not nearly as fast as the for loop version.
Btw: You're right, I only loop over one matrix triangle - the other triangle will be created like this: ``L = tril(L,-1)+tril(L,-1)'``

Comment: Matlab's JIT is very good at optimizing 'fortran-style' for-loops, that is hard to beat. A common complaint is also that arrayfun is a bit slow ...

Comment: Another problem with the vectorized version is that you have to pre-compute `A`, `B` and `C`. Especially the latter might take up a lot of useless memory if `x` is big. Its size probably scales with `n^3`, ouch. Your for loop does not suffer from this problem. To solve this problem, you might try to compute `c` on each iteration, I will edit the answer ...

Comment: I just tried replacing the ``if`` with ``L(a,b) = all(...)``. Funnily enough this also slows down the runtime by approx. 50 %.

Comment: That is weird, no idea why the `if` is faster. Try without the `if` and define `L = false(n)` to prevent the bool to double conversion. Please accept the answer when you are happy, I am done playing with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, `L(a, b) == 1` if for any c with a < c < b, (c, x(c)) is “below” the line connecting (a, x(a)) and (b, x(b)), right?

It is not a vectorization, but I found the other approach. Rather than comparing all c with a < c < b for each new b, I saved the maximum slope from a to c in (a, b), and used it for (a, b + 1). (I tried with only one direction, but I think that using both directions is also possible.)

```
x = x(:);
n = length(x);
L = zeros(n);

for a = 1:(n - 1)
  L(a, a + 1) = 1;
  maxSlope = x(a + 1) - x(a);
  for b = (a + 2):n
    currSlope = (x(b) - x(a)) / (b - a);
    if currSlope > maxSlope
      maxSlope = currSlope;
      L(a, b) = 1;
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know your data, but with some random data, the result is the same with original code (with transpose).

Comment: Nice work, on my laptop (with Matlab R2012b) it's about twice as fast as the original code.

Comment: Really? Maybe I misplaced `tic;toc` when I checked runtime.

Comment: For ``n=100`` my code usually takes about 0.04 seconds, while yours is done in about 0.02 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

An esoteric answer:  You could do the calculations for every a,b,c from 1:n, exclude the don't cares, and then do the all along the c dimension.

```
[a, b, c] = ndgrid(1:n, 1:n, 1:n);

La = x(c)' < x(b) + (x(a) - x(b)) .* ((b - c)./(b-a));
La(b >= a | c <= b | c >= a) = true;

L = all(La, 3);
```

Though the jit would probably do just fine with the for loops since they do very little.

Edit: still uses all of the memory, but with less maths

```
[A, B, C] = ndgrid(1:n, 1:n, 1:n);

valid = B < A & C > B & C < A;
a = A(valid); b = B(valid); c = C(valid);

La = true(size(A));
La(valid) = x(c)' < x(b) + (x(a) - x(b)) .* ((b - c)./(b-a));
L = all(La, 3);
```

Edit2: alternate last line to add the clause that c of no elements is true

```
L = all(La,3) | ~any(valid,3);
```

Comment: Good job! It takes about 3 times as long as the loop-version on my machine...I guess the guys at Mathworks really have done a lot to improve the speed of loops in Matlab. Otherwise, I can't explain to myself why all the great vectorized versions seem to be slower...

Comment: One reason this version might be slow is that `a`, `b`, `c` and `La` all take `O(n^3)` space, while the for-loop only uses `O(n^2)` space.